# Transform property apparently not working with display flex

Tags: html, css, transform

Hi All any help with this would be great.
What I am trying to achieve is to have an effect which increases the font size of my navigation `li` while hovering over them. Previously I have used : transform: scale(1.5) but since I have tried to use this within a flexbox container it seems not work. I'm new to flexbox.
Here's my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;1,300&display=swap');
:root {
  --text-primary: #fff;
  --text-secondary: #3d58b8;
  --text-bg-dark: #333;
  --text-bg-light: #333;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: white;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.span-1 {
  color: var(--text-secondary);
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #042322;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: var(--text-primary);
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--text-primary);
  transform: scale(21.5);
}

.hero {
  background: url('/css/imgs/bg_1.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  color: var(--text-primary)
}

.hero .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.hero::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c01f624491.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="hero">
  <div class="navbar">
    <h1 class="logo"><span class="span-1">Templates</span> R Us
    </h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Welcome to Templates R Us</h1>
    <p>Where your desires meet our possibilities</p>
    <a class="btn" href="">Explore More</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

```
This is the link to my code:
https://codepen.io/Helye23/pen/oNbaYWO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `nav ul li a{ display: inline-block }` worked for me.